# Ref Cursor and Resultset

Tags: java, oracle, cursor

I am calling a store procedure from my java class that returns me a ref cursor, I am extracting out the result set from the cursor and iterating the result set for my use, now my question is this

is the returned ref cursor has all the data in it or it again goes to the database server when the getObject is called on the cursor for result set ?

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fetch Size](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm#sthref1000) is the Oracle parameter you are looking for. It is a very important setting if your application involves transferring data from the Server to a Client.

You can set the fetch size for your statement using this method.

```
void setFetchSize(int rows) throws SQLException
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm#sthref1000

From the link above...

> By default, when Oracle JDBC executes a query, it receives the result
>   set 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default
>   Oracle row-prefetch value. You can change the number of rows retrieved
>   with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row-prefetch
>   value (see "Oracle Row Prefetching" for more information).
>
> When the statement object executes a query, the fetch size of the
>   statement object is passed to the result set object produced by the
>   query. However, you can also set the fetch size in the result set
>   object to override the statement fetch size that was passed to it.

Answer (score 4):

Typically there will be a buffer on the client associated with the cursor.  When you ask for the first row, the oracle server will fill the buffer with row data for the cursor.  If not all the row data will fit in the buffer, some subsequent call on the cursor will get the next n rows from the server.